# Adaptive counting sort for integer arrays in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

(See the [next iteration](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/adaptive-counting-sort-for-integer-arrays-in-java-follow-up).)

I have this *adaptive* counting sort for integer arrays. Basically, it maintains a doubly-linked list of nodes. Each node knows its integer \$a_i\$ and contains the counter describing the number of \$a_i\$ encountered so far in the range. As you might know, the running time of counting sort is \$\mathcal{O}(n + k)\$, where \$k = \max a_i - \min a_i\$ is the "width" of the input array, which limits its applicability in general case. The linked list structure allows sorting even for large values of \$k\$. Also, as an optimization, the adaptive version knows the previous node incremented, which allows it to adapt to "closeness" of integers in the array.

The running time, in my opinion, varies between \$\Omega(n)\$ and \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$, although I don't have a formal proof. The space requirements are, however, easy to calculate: its the amount of **distinct** integers in the requested range.

As that adaptive sort seems to have quadratic running time in the worst case, I don't hope it to be comparable to `java.util.Arrays.sort(int[])`.
The included demonstration, however, compares my sort against an optimized insertion sort (called "straight insertion sort" as far as I can remember) that minimizes the number of assignments. I won't include all information that the included demonstration prints, but the total running time is of order:

> ```
> Total insertion sort time: 29091 milliseconds.
> Total counting sort time:  4595 milliseconds.
> ```

In the demo, I considered two types of arrays: arrays with small number of distinct elements, and presorted arrays with small number of runs.

I know that intuition is not as good as a proof, yet it is a good starting point. If you plot in \$x,y\$ - plane points \$(i, a_i)\$, and then "draw" the curve through them, the intuition seems to be that the "smoother" the curve, the higher is performance of my implementation.

**net.coderodde.util.sorting.CountingSort.java**:

```java
package net.coderodde.util.sorting;

/**
 * This class implements an adaptive counting sort that adapts to the input.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class CountingSort {

    /**
     * Sorts the entire input integer array.
     * 
     * @param array the integer array to sort.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], ...,
     * array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]}.
     * 
     * @param array     the array containing the range to sort.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive range index.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive range index.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        if (toIndex - fromIndex < 2) {
            return;
        }

        int lastElement = array[fromIndex];
        Node head = new Node(lastElement);
        Node tail = head;
        Node last = head;

        for (int i = fromIndex + 1; i < toIndex; ++i) {
            int currentElement = array[i];

            if (currentElement < lastElement) {
                Node tmp = last.prev;

                while (tmp != null && tmp.element > currentElement) {
                    tmp = tmp.prev;
                }

                if (tmp == null) {
                    Node newnode = new Node(currentElement);
                    newnode.next = head;
                    head.prev = newnode;
                    head = newnode;
                    last = head;
                } else if (tmp.element == currentElement) {
                    tmp.count++;
                    last = tmp;
                } else {
                    // Insert a new node between 'tmp' and 'tmp.next'.
                    Node newnode = new Node(currentElement);
                    newnode.prev = tmp;
                    newnode.next = tmp.next;
                    newnode.prev.next = newnode;
                    newnode.next.prev = newnode;
                    last = newnode;
                }
            } else if (currentElement > lastElement) {
                Node tmp = last.next;

                while (tmp != null && tmp.element < currentElement) {
                    tmp = tmp.next;
                }

                if (tmp == null) {
                    Node newnode = new Node(currentElement);
                    newnode.prev = tail;
                    tail.next = newnode;
                    tail = newnode;
                    last = newnode;
                } else if (tmp.element == currentElement) {
                    tmp.count++;
                    last = tmp;
                } else {
                    // Insert a new node between 'tmp.prev' and 'tmp'.
                    Node newnode = new Node(currentElement);
                    newnode.prev = tmp.prev;
                    newnode.next = tmp;
                    tmp.prev.next = newnode;
                    tmp.prev = newnode;
                    last = newnode;
                }
            } else {
                last.count++;
            }

            lastElement = currentElement;
        }

        // Now rebuild the requested range.
        int index = fromIndex;

        for (Node node = head; node != null; node = node.next) {
            int element = node.element;

            for (int i = 0; i < node.count; ++i) {
                array[index++] = element;
            }
        }
    }  

    private static final class Node {

        Node(int element) {
            this.element = element;
            this.count = 1;
        }

        Node prev;
        Node next;
        int element;
        int count;
    }
}
```

**net.coderodde.util.sorting.Insertionsort.java**:

```java
package net.coderodde.util.sorting;

/**
 * This class provides a static method for sorting integer arrays using 
 * insertion sort.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 */
public class Insertionsort {

    /**
     * Sorts the entire input integer array.
     * 
     * @param array the integer array to sort.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array) {
        sort(array, 0, array.length);
    }

    /**
     * Sorts the range {@code array[fromIndex], array[fromIndex + 1], ...,
     * array[toIndex - 2], array[toIndex - 1]}.
     * 
     * @param array     the array containing the range to sort.
     * @param fromIndex the starting, inclusive range index.
     * @param toIndex   the ending, exclusive range index.
     */
    public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
        for (int i = fromIndex + 1; i < toIndex; ++i) {
            int element = array[i];
            int j = i;

            for (; j > fromIndex && array[j - 1] > element; --j) {
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
            }

            array[j] = element;
        }
    }    
}
```

**Demo.java**:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import net.coderodde.util.sorting.CountingSort;
import net.coderodde.util.sorting.Insertionsort;

public class Demo {

    /**
     * The number of iterations for each array type.
     */
    private static final int OPERATION_COUNT = 30;

    /**
     * The maximum length of the array to profile against.
     */
    private static final int LENGTH = 40000;

    /**
     * The assumed console window width in characters.
     */
    private static final int CONSOLE_WIDTH = 80;

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        long seed = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Random random = new Random(seed);

        int[] array1;
        int[] array2;

        long totalMySort = 0L;
        long totalInsertionsort = 0L;

        System.out.println("Seed: " + seed);
        System.out.println(title("Random arrays"));

        //// RANDOM ARRAYS ////
        for (int op = 0; op < OPERATION_COUNT; ++op) {
            int maxValue = 20 + 20 * op;
            System.out.println("Max value: " + maxValue);

            array1 = getRandomIntegerArray(LENGTH, maxValue, random);
            array2 = array1.clone();

            int fromIndex = random.nextInt(LENGTH / 20);
            int toIndex = LENGTH - random.nextInt(LENGTH / 20);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CountingSort.sort(array1, fromIndex, toIndex);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long duration = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.println("Counting sort in " + duration 
                                                   + " milliseconds.");

            totalMySort += duration;

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Insertionsort.sort(array2, fromIndex, toIndex);
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            duration = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.println("Insertion sort in " + duration
                                                    + " milliseconds.");
            System.out.println(bar());
            totalInsertionsort += duration;

            if (!Arrays.equals(array1, array2)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Sorts did not agree.");
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(title("Presorted arrays"));

        //// PRESORTED ARRAYS ////
        for (int op = 0; op < OPERATION_COUNT; ++op) {
            int runAmount = 20 + 20 * op;
            System.out.println("Run amount: " + runAmount);

            array1 = getPresortedIntegerArray(LENGTH, runAmount, random);
            array2 = array1.clone();

            int fromIndex = random.nextInt(LENGTH / 20);
            int toIndex = LENGTH - random.nextInt(LENGTH / 20);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CountingSort.sort(array1, fromIndex, toIndex);
            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long duration = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.println("Counting sort in " + duration 
                                                   + " milliseconds.");

            totalMySort += duration;

            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Insertionsort.sort(array2, fromIndex, toIndex);
            endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            duration = endTime - startTime;

            System.out.println("Insertion sort in " + duration
                                                    + " milliseconds.");
            System.out.println(bar());
            totalInsertionsort += duration;

            if (!Arrays.equals(array1, array2)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Sorts did not agree.");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total insertion sort time: " + 
                           totalInsertionsort + " milliseconds.");
        System.out.println("Total counting sort time:  " + 
                           totalMySort + " milliseconds.");
    }

    private static int[] getRandomIntegerArray(int size, 
                                               int maxValue, 
                                               Random random) {
        return IntStream.range(0, size)
                        .map((i) -> random.nextInt(maxValue))
                        .toArray();
    }

    private static int[] getPresortedIntegerArray(int size, 
                                                  int runs, 
                                                  Random random) {
        int[] ret = getRandomIntegerArray(size, size, random);
        int chunkSize = size / runs + 1;
        int chunkId = 0;

        for (; chunkId < size / chunkSize; chunkId++) {
            Arrays.sort(ret, 
                        chunkSize * chunkId, 
                        Math.min(size, (chunkId + 1) * chunkSize));
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static String title(String s) {
        int textWithSpacesLength = s.length() + 2;
        int leftBarLength = (CONSOLE_WIDTH - textWithSpacesLength) / 2;
        int rightBarLength = CONSOLE_WIDTH - leftBarLength 
                                           - textWithSpacesLength;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(CONSOLE_WIDTH);

        for (int i = 0; i < leftBarLength; ++i) {
            sb.append('-');
        }

        sb.append(' ').append(s).append(' ');

        for (int i = 0; i < rightBarLength; ++i) {
            sb.append('-');
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static String bar() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(CONSOLE_WIDTH);

        for (int i = 0; i < CONSOLE_WIDTH; ++i) {
            sb.append('-');
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How should I refactor the implementation in order to increase its maintainability/readability?
2. Is there any room for optimization?
3. What do you think of this algorithm?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would ever use this over a radix sort.  The radix sort uses the same sort of principles, except it is able to restrict the range to a certain number of bits (usually 8 bits or 256 buckets).

Comment: I have to disagree here: suppose you pass an array containing the same integer to radix sort. Assuming 8 bits, it will iterate through the entire range 4 times. Couting sort would be done in one pass.

Comment: On the other hand, if there are no duplicates, this sort is essentially an insertion sort, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it would seem so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The sheer size and repetitive nature of `Insertionsort.sort` suggests splitting it up into methods, such as:

  ```
  find_forward()
  find_backward()
  insert_before()
  insert_after()
  ```
- I don't see any benefit of starting a search form a `last` node. Always searching from the `head` gives the same asymptotic complexity (and assuming uniform inputs, the same worst case), and simplifies the logic.

Answer (score 2):

## Could use TreeMap instead of linked list

The good part about this counting sort is the handling of duplicate entries: you just increment a count.  The bad part is searching through a list to find the current entry.  You could do better by using a `TreeMap` instead of a linked list, to reduce your linear search time to logarithmic.  I believe this makes the total sort time \$O(n \log n)\$.

I think the code looks simpler also:

```
public static void sort(int[] array, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    TreeMap<Integer,Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();

    // Add all array entries into the tree map.
    for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
        int     key   = array[i];
        Integer count = treeMap.get(key);
        if (count != null) {
            treeMap.put(key, count+1);
        } else {
            treeMap.put(key, 1);
        }
    }

    // Pull out the entries from the tree map in order.
    int index = fromIndex;
    while (true) {
        Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = treeMap.pollFirstEntry();

        if (entry == null) {
            break;
        }
        int key   = entry.getKey();
        int count = entry.getValue();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            array[index++] = key;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output results**

The sort runs faster also:

> ```
> Total insertion sort time: 12003 milliseconds.
> Total counting sort time:  477 milliseconds.
> ```

Comment: No. Even better. I believe this is \$\mathcal{O}(n \log k)\$.

Comment: ..., where \$k\$ is the number of distinct keys, not \$\max a_i - \min a_i\$.